# Пушкин о двенадцати

Tags: словообразование, морфология, числительные, морфемный-разбор

Преобладающая точка зрения: сложное числительное *двенадцать* имеет корни числительных *два* и *десят*ь.

В Критических заметках А.С. Пушкина (Сочинения. Том V, стр. 136. СПб 1887) утверждается, что *12* «сокращено из *двое*». Почему бы не принять (учесть) точку зрения поэта, полагая, что исключение из слова только буквы *О* заодно объяснит наличие оставшейся *Е*?

Answer (score 1):

Это лишь гипотеза, которой не находится подкрепления (напр. в виде присутствия признаков собирательной формы числительного при образовании прочих -надцати). У Фасмера же приводятся две реально существовавших альтернативных древнерусских формы (дъванадесѩте и дъвѣнадесѩте), образованных через числительные два/две (м. и ж. рода), от одной из которых (ж. р.) -е- и закрепилось позже.

Comment: А какая сила закрепила позже это -е-? Есть гипотеза?

Comment: Гипотетически, сила благозвучия - в интересах разборчивости на слух :) "Дванадцать" неудобно тем, что слог  с "а" не контрастирует по гласной с "надцатью" (два подряд слога с "а"), как это имеет место в остальных числительных той же группы.

Comment: Заметьте, в украинском сохранилось *а*: дванадцять

Comment: Значит, это лишь гипотеза. Кстати, надо было полностью процитировать Пушкина. Заметка такая: «Двенадцать, а не двѣнадцать — сокращение изъ двое, какъ три изъ трое».